# How to modify class design to make it thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am thinking potentially my design has left me in a situation which makes thread safety impossible. If this is the case, would someone potentially be able to help by providing some suggestions to change this around a little?

I have a class which represents CurrentBidders

```
public final class Bidders {

    private static volatile ConcurrentMap<String, BidValue> bidders = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BidValue>();

    public Bidders(ConcurrentMap<String, BidValue currentBidders){
        if(bidders != null){
            bidders = currentBidders;
        }
    }

    public static synchronized ConcurrentMap<String, BidValue> getBidders(){
        return bidders;
    }

    public static synchronized void updateBidder(String bidderName, BidValue value){
        if(value != null){
            bidders.put(bidderName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I can foresee - for example - that a modification to the map might occur using update bidder and getBidders might be called before it is completed leaving inconsistent state. However I need to make this state accessible through my application for various updates.

Can anyone suggest how i could approach this differently / in a better approach (i.e. name some techniques that i can research to help me make a more robust application)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a modification to the map might occur using update bidder and getBidders might be called before it is completed leaving inconsistent state

You're using a `ConcurrentMap`, it is built to cope with those situations already.

The use of `static`s, injecting the map in a constructor, returning the map, are all huge code smells, but I can't see why you are doing any of those from the limited code posted. My `Bidders` would start like this, this is threadsafe, the reasons are in comments:

```
public final class Bidders {

    // I don't need a concurrent map any longer, I'm in control of the concurrency within
    // this class.
    private final Map<String, BidValue> bidders = new HashMap<String, BidValue>();

    public void updateBidder(String bidderName, BidValue value) {
        if (value != null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                // ensures we do not add while we're enumerating
                bidders.put(bidderName, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<PlayerBid> getBids() {
        List<PlayerBid> bids = new ArrayList<PlayerBid>();
        synchronized (this) {
            // ensures we do not add while we're enumerating,
            // if we returned the map
            // we couldn't guarantee this would happen.
            for (Entry<String, BidValue> entry : bidders.entrySet()) {
                bids.add(new PlayerBid(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
        return bids;
    }

    // add other methods as you need, but avoid returning the internals of
    // this class
}
```

## Singleton

It looks like a you're after a singleton, after all that's what a `static` field is and while I'd recommend limiting use of the singleton pattern, this is how you'd do that:

```
public enum Bidders {

    INSTANCE;

    //Everything below here is exactly as previous example.

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, BidValue> bidders = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BidValue>();

    public void updateBidder(String bidderName, BidValue value){
      //.. exactly as previous example
    }

    //.. exactly as previous example
}
```

Usage:

```
Bidders.INSTANCE.updateBidder(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i though as much when i read the comment `but avoid returning the internals of this class` - however if another object needs to know the current bidders how would one go about that without returning the internals of the class

Comment: also regarding the singleton - is that not considered an anti pattern?

Comment: What does the other class need to know exactly?

Comment: What bidders there are available at that time

Comment: Singleton is, that's why I recommend caution, but when you declare a `static` field, that's a single instance for the whole program, so you had that anyway.

Comment: Just the names of the current bidders? Show me the code that uses that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62913/discussion-between-biscuit128-and-weston).

Answer (score 0):

You want to be careful with the approach you are taking. You are merely wrapping around an object that is already thread save and creating the illusion that you application becomes thread safe by virtue of that. You should really be looking at your 'business logic' and making that thread safe. Exposing your `ConcurrentHashMap` actually undermines your thread safety.

So work on an approach that start with an interface like this:

```
public interface BidManager {
    void registerBid (String bidderName, BidValue bidValue);

    void stopBids();

    boolean hasBid(String bidderName);

    void calculateWinningBid();

    String getWinnnigBidderName();

    BidValue getWinningBidValue();

}
```

And work down from there, ensuring firstly, that you can implement this interface in a thread safe manner, then set up a way to get these `BidManager` objects in a thread safe manner, either by using a singleton pattern, or by some other means.